# From word to Latex using pandoc , problem with citation

Tags: ms-word, latex, pandoc

My main propose of using pandoc is to make word documents from latex files, so I share them with my  colleagues for review. I am new in pandoc, so I used a straightforward example.
I used pandoc to create a docx file form a simple Latex tex file, which had a simple one citation. The docx file is created successfully, However,  when I wanted to reverse the process and create a Latex file from the newly created docx file. The citations are copied in the newly tex file just as simple text, without any citation command in latex. Is there any way you can transfer citations from docx file to latex  file, and store them is some kind bib file  through panndoc?

```
-s input.tex --bibliography=b.bib -o output.docx
-s output.docx --bibliography=b.bib -o input.tex
```

Comment: I don't think so.. most people write markdown and convert to latex... but even there you have to write the .bib file yourself (or use a tool from LaTeX-land..)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, do you have any specific Latex tools in mind ?

Comment: hm... http://www.bibtex.org/Links/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the word reference style to "export bibtex" and at least you can copy paste the references into a bibtex file. References inside the text are kind of okay. References in footnotes don't work so well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).